# How to correctly fix a list of links in python3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup

After using beautiful soup's `soup.findAll('a', {'link': 'go to'})` I extracted a list of links like:

```
lis_links = ['https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 234.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 23.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV24.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 120.xml https://foo.com/WERW FOR INJ.xml']
```

As you can see the some links have  "", **how to fix that blank space with it's proper encoding (I guess its `%20`)?**. I tried to use `replace(' ', '%20')` but I do not have control of where to use it.

Comment: You only have one item in your list. Are you sure the beautifulsoup is correct?

Comment: Yes, it pulled several links since several links on the site have the "go to"

Comment: That method should return a list of more than one item is all I'm saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to find all spaces not followed by *http* : `\s(?!http)`

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/EOobTt/1)

**Python sample**

```
import re

def fixLinks(str):
   return re.sub(r"\s(?!http)", "%20", str)

links = ["https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 234.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 23.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV24.xml https://foo.com/019774_s009_TEV 120.xml https://foo.com/WERW FOR INJ.xml"]

links[0] = fixLinks(links[0])

print links[0];
```

[Python online demo](https://repl.it/HKeh/1)

Comment: Let me check this solution... Thanks!!

Comment: don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes, I am checking them... It seems that I still have issues... Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, although it fixed some urls there are other urls that still have the ` ` issue... hold on, let me check again..

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` is it possible to wrap this into a function?... I tried to:`       9 
     10 def fix_urls2(row):
---> 11     row[0] = re.sub(r"\s(?!http)", "%20", row[0])
     12     return row[0]`